# Set Interface Builder Object Coordinates in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

First question on StackOverflow, so please excuse me if I haven't done all the proper steps, although I've tried searching for an answer for a while now.

I'm trying to change the coordinates of multiple objects in a UIView from Interface Builder when the iPhone changes from portrait mode to landscape mode. I don't want so scale the view, but I want to rearrange the objects in it when the iPhone turns into landscape mode, so that all the objects will fit better. Currently I'm looking for a way to programmatically set the X,Y coordinates, but if there is a better way to go about doing this, let me know.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
    /* Move IBOutlets to different X,Y coordinates  */

}   
return YES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` should only be used the answer the question of whether the view supports a particular orientation.  Use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` or `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` to rearrange objects.

Actually, it would probably be even better to subclass `UIView` and override `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Sounds good, but how would I end up changing the location of those objects?

Comment: Assuming you have set up IB outlets (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CodeIntegration/CodeIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH18), just set the object's frame or center, like `self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 10, 10, 200, 20 )`